# Adding checkbox using suite script 2

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm new to suite scripting. And I'm just wondering, can I add a checkbox on an existing custom record - form using a user event script (beforeload) ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The scriptContext of beforeLoad has the current form. Its type is serverWidget.Form so you can use addField like below:

```
scriptContext.form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_abc',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX,
    label: 'ABC'
});
```

Comment: thanks jala. it worked :) All I use is form didn't  know that I can using scriptContext.form.